# Generate Key from Plaintext?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I need to generate a random Key from both plain text and any parameters(system  time or salt).
Is this possible in Java, and what class/method combination should I be looking at to do so?

Comment: Google `generate a random key with java` and take your pick.

Comment: How can i do that in java?

Comment: You don't need _java_ to make a google search; simply search it up on any present-day web browser.

Comment: What's the point of the "key"? You should describe what it is used for.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at classes in `javax.crypto` package, like

```
javax.crypto.Cipher;
javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
javax.crypto.SecretKey;
```

here is an example:

```
public static String generateSymmetricKey() {

    KeyGenerator keyGenerator;
    try {
        keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGenerator.init(128);
        SecretKey key = keyGenerator.generateKey();

        Cipher encodeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
        encodeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        String bigSecret = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(
                key.getEncoded());

        return bigSecret;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Secret Key generation failed: "
                + e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

As a result you will get Base64 encoded, encrypted according to "AES/CTR/NoPadding" specification symmetric key.

Then there is a question - do you really need a random **key** from "plain text", salt, timestamp?
Or do you need to encrypt your "plain text" with a key and salt?

What is a purpose of "plain text" for **Random** Key?

Usually there is a path:

1. You have a value and a key
2. you encrypt your value with a key
3. To keep your key secret you need to encrypt key it-self and store it somewhere.As long as key is a byte array it is better to have it encoded as String for easy storing somewhere.
4. when you need to decrypt a value - you restore a key and then use it to decrypt your value.

Comment: Very thanks for your answer. i have a symmetric stream algorithm that i use to enc/dec a field in DB . but the problem when that data is duplicated in any field . this yield to the same cipher. i used your  generateSymmetricKey() function. it's very good but in the case of duplication, it gives a different cipher data but ends with the same char

Comment: sample of data is below where the "2020273/2!1'2!1!273" is repeated in 3 data cells where it is identical plain text data #3)240%2/1!2.2%3,2!3'2!2%3.3-120-021'1"2/1+2020273/2!1'2!1!273           %2*2.2$15021123230!1/1.0.0%25023"023/2+1'2&0020273/2!1'2!1!273         $3.0.1.3$2*2#130+1+022)1#2$3'2&3"2"21331#2"0020273/2!1'2!1!273

Comment: That is correct. Same key+same data,+same algorithm = same cipher. But... there are much more algorithms than AES (as example "PBEwithMD5andDES") and things like IV, salt, iteration count, nonce, padding... just check it further and you can easily get not the same cipher for the same data. Topic is very large. API for all of those is in  `javax.crypto` package. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer